Rules for Hooks in React Native
Are the same rules for hooks in React applicable to React Native:
There are 3 rules for hooks:
Hooks can only be called inside React function components. [Add React Native Components]
Hooks can only be called at the top level of a component.
Hooks cannot be conditional
I have search in vain for this on the web. If you also point me to a good site for using hooks in React Native or differences with hooks (if any) in React Native.
Thanks in advance.
I have searched the web for React Native rules for hooks and can only find the rules for React.

Yes, the same rules apply.

Hooks function the same in react native and react.
